# LinkedIn Shares API - Pagination not working properly

Tags: api, pagination, linkedin-api

Shares API call has some issues regarding the records returned with pagination. I passed different numbers as count but it didn't return exact number of records in element attribute.
Eg:

1. API call with count 10 - returns 10 or less amount of records
2. API call with count 50 - returns 45 records
3. API call with count 100 - returns 70 records
4. API call with count 120 - returns Bad request(400) error

What is the reason for this issue? Is there a maximum limit for count parameter? Could you please assist on this issue?

Comment: Probably same problem as this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655719/999, and your question helped me find the solution that I ended up with.