# LinkedIn API returns empty shares / posts and for adAnalyticsV2 nothing and empty for shares

Tags: linkedin-api

for my request:

```
 https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:9,year:2020),end:(day:1,month:9,year:2021))&timeGranularity=DAILY&pivot=SHARE&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange,impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,pivot,pivotValue&companies=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<ORGANIZATION_ID>)
```

I get always empty return. What could it be? I do have all the required
Permissions:

r_1st_connections_size, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social

My goal is to get metrics as likes, impression for all my / organizations posts.
I appreaciate any input, thanks a lot.

As return I get:

```
{
    "paging": {
        "start": 0,
        "count": 10,
        "links": []
    },
    "elements": []
}
```

Where for my shares:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:company:<MY_ORGANIZATION_ID>
```

I get an empty paging but with the right total count:

```
{
    "paging": {
        "start": 0,
        "count": 10,
        "links": [
            {
                "type": "application/json",
                "rel": "next",
                "href": "/v2/shares?count=10&owners=urn%3Ali%3Acompany%3A<MY_ORGANIZATION_ID>&q=owners&start=0"
            }
        ],
        "total": 569
    },
    "elements": []
}
```

Of course I use the generated bearer token for the request for which I have the listed permissions when I check in the https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/token-inspector.

I'm looking forward to any input and help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with the API and how it filters the data. I ran into the same issue and just kept trying.

I came to the conclusion that you have to ignore that the documentation tells you that you [reached the end of the data if there are less results in the response than you requested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/pagination?context=linkedin/marketing/context#end-of-the-dataset). Also ignore the pagination info given in the request.

In your example you use the defaults for `sharesPerOwner` and `count`. You may want to include at least `sharesPerOwner`, because that defaults to 1. I worked with `count=5` and `sharesPerOwner=3000` (that's the max value allowed).

And for me I got 3 results when try with `count=5&start=0`. It tells me to get the next page with `count=5&start=3`, but when I try that, then I get no results. Next I tried `count=5&start=5`. No result there, either. *But:* My next attempt with `count=5&start=10` returned a record. Just one, but more than none - and I kept increasing `start` by `count` over and over again. That worked until my start reached 3000 (`sharesPerOwner`?). I didn't get 3000 records, but ~1600.

So what I think is happening is that the API gathers records in a temp table. Something like this:

| Records | start=0 | start=3 | start=5 | start=10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Record 1 | < |  |  |  |
| Record 2 | < |  |  |  |
| Record 3 | < |  |  |  |
| null | < | < |  |  |
| null | < | < |  |  |
| null |  | < | < |  |
| null |  | < | < |  |
| null |  | < | < |  |
| null |  |  | < |  |
| null |  |  | < |  |
| Record 5 |  |  |  | < |
| null |  |  |  | < |
| null |  |  |  | < |
| null |  |  |  | < |
| null |  |  |  | < |

But that table has "dead" records and is too stupid to deal with them.

**TLDR;**
My conclusion: Keep increasing `start` step by step (and work with a bigger `count`) until you have all the data you need. Don't let it confuse you with what seems to be the end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you may not have the admin access on the company page, you'll likely need to obtain a proper API key and secret to interact with the page via the Linkedin API.